# want to trigger an activity when the keyboard is used in android and stop it and pass a value when the keyboard is closes?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have created my own input method in android and in that i want to trigger this activity to count backspaces when it started running and send a value when the user closes the keyboard? is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onKey()` method of your IME keep a count of backspace key.

```
@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] ints) {
    -----
    -----
    if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE){
        count++;
    }
    ----
    ----
}
```

Reset this counter in `onStartInputView()` method.

Now in `onFinishInput()` method, trigger the activity you want and put the number of backspaces as extras.

```
@Override
 public void onFinishInput(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("backspace_count",count);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onFinish();
}
```

I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.